# Change buttons in Xeditable with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a question.
Is it possible to change the save(submit) button and cancel buttons by links in Xeditable for AngularJS?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way was changing the css style of the button to look like a link

```
button {
     background:none!important;
     border:none; 
     padding:0!important;
     font: inherit;
     /*border is optional*/
     border-bottom:1px solid #444; 
     cursor: pointer;
}
```